# How should I model rotation caused by bounce friction?

Tags: java, 2d, rotation, physics

In my Java2D simulation, I have a disc which, when it bounces off the boundary of a 2D region, begins to rotate, as if it had gotten some spin from the wall.

[image: The situation]

I'm having trouble relating the collision vectors and the angular velocity of the spin that should result.

How should I approach this?

Comment: The first answer says 'cross of incident and normal'. Its unclear if its velocity vector or position vector.

Comment: It has to be the velocity. Position vectors are always rooted at `0,0` and so their direction doesn't have much meaning. (Consequently, crossing them with something wouldn't do anything very interesting.)